# Definition regarding $L_2$-norm. Is $\|u\|_{L_2(\Omega)} \geq \|u\|_{L_2(\Gamma)} \ ?$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

In my book there is this definition:

> **Definition:** *The space of all square integrable functions over a given domain* $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$ *is known as the*
>   $L_2(\Omega)$*-space.* *If* $u \in L_2(\Omega),$ *then the* $L_2$*-norm of*
>   $u$ *(in 1-D case) is*
>   $$\|u\|_{L_2(\Omega)}=\sqrt{(u,u)}=\left(\int_{\Omega}|u(x)|^2 \
>  dx\right)^{1/2}.\tag1$$

**Questions:**

1. Denote the boundary of $\Omega$ as $\partial\Omega=\Gamma$. Then, is it always true that $$\|u\|_{L_2(\Omega)} \geq \|u\|_{L_2(\Gamma)}, \tag 2$$
   and how can one prove/explain it?
2. How would the above look like if we, for example, dealt with $\Omega=[a,b]\times[a,b]$? How would $\Gamma$ look like then?

Comment: How are you defining $L_2(\Gamma)$? Integral over an $(n-1)$-dimensional surface?

Comment: For $\Omega$ closed, 1 is true. For $\Omega$ open, not necessarily. You could have a function $u$ be zero on $\Omega$ and equal to $1$ on the boundary, for example.

2. then $\Gamma = \{(x,y) | x = a\} \cup \{(x,y) | x = b\} \cup \{(x,y) | y = a\} \cup \{(x,y) | y = b\}$

Comment: Why don't you try with $\Omega = [0,1]$ ? It is obvious that $|f(0)|$, assuming it is well-defined, isn't constrained by $\|f\|_{L^2[0,1]}$, assuming it is non-zero. In general $f(0)$ isn't well-defined and $f\to f(0)$ is a densely defined unbounded operator.

Comment: @angryavian - This is the problem, my book never defines it but they use it anyway. But they way they use it indicates to me that they do infact define it as the integral over an $(n-1)$- dimensional surface.

Comment: @reuns - Could you please elaborate on how you set up the integrals in order to show $(2)?$

Comment: (2) is not true, try with $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: The definition says "domain", which are open by definition.